# subprocess.Popen won't execute

Tags: python, subprocess

In my code I have the following:

```
...
subp_001 =  subprocess.Popen('./my001Script.sh %s %s' % (param1, param2), shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)    
#atexit.register(subp_001.terminate)
time.sleep(5)
os.killpg(subp_001.pid, signal.SIGTERM) 
...
```

At some moment, verything was working, that means my001Script runs then the execution of the rest of the python code stops for that 5 seconds the afet rthat the script is killed, then I don't remember exactly what I have changed that made my001Script never runs again, unless I take off time.sleep().
I would like to find a way to execute the script and after some seconds I kill it.
I've also tried to do the following instead:

```
...
subp_001 =  subprocess.Popen('./my001Script.sh %s %s' % (param1, param2), shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)    
#atexit.register(subp_001.terminate)
threading.Timer(5,killingBroadcastAck).start()
...
```

Same thing, my001Script is not executing at all, by the way I realize that if it does not execute I should expect an error at os.killpg(subp_001.pid, signal.SIGTERM). I don't get such error.

Any hints ?

Comment: What `pgrep -f my001Script.sh` produces *before* `subprocess.Popen`.  I don't see the argument for `killingBroadcastAck` function: it might kill the wrong process if `subp_001` is created several times. `Timer()` is the easy way if you need something done in 5 seconds without blocking.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me with these minimal tests. Are you sure your script is really not executing?

This runs the process, which is completed in less than 5 secs, and then gives an error as can't kill the process that wasn't there anymore I think:

```
p = subprocess.Popen('echo hello', shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
print "done"
time.sleep(5)
os.killpg(p.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
print "waited"
```

output:

```
done
hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

And then when change the sleep to 0 so it's quick enough to kill the process while it's still there it again works as expected:

```
p = subprocess.Popen('echo hello', shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
print "done"
time.sleep(0)
os.killpg(p.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
print "waited"
```

outputs:

```
done
waited
```

Comment: All right, I find out a weird behaviour of 
    p = subprocess.Popen(./my001Script.sh %s %s' % (param1, param2), shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid),
because it actually won't pop up (since it consist on xterm -hold  -e ...) or I don't know why exactly the expected result didn't come up, 
And above all, when I try another script ./my002Script.sh it works fine when just followed my time.sleep(x).